# Azure AD SCIM - How to Enable the Provisioning Section

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim2

I need Azure AD users to be synced into my application, so I've been researching how to implement SCIM and configure Azure AD to work with it. My end goal is to have my application listed as the ones here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/tutorial-list, and to do this, it should support SSO + User provisioning.

The implementation is kind of straightforward as SCIM is a standard and I just need to implement a bunch of APIs complying with a specific contract, so this should work.

The problem I'm having, though, is I cannot find how to enable the "Provisioning" feature for my application. I've been reading the articles and watching the videos Microsoft provided (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/configure-automatic-user-provisioning-portal for instance) and it seems that when I click the Provisioning section in my app, I should be able to configure it. Unfortunately, I don't see the UI shown in the tutorials, so I suppose I've been missing some step that is not explained in the docs. Also, I'd expect to have somewhere to configure the base URL that should contain all endpoints required for the SCIM standard. I don't see this either, which confirms my feeling I'm missing something essential.

Here are the steps I've been taking:

1. Open the Azure portal
2. Create an enterprise app - Click on Enterprise applications, Create your own application, and Integrate any other application you don't find in the gallery (Non-gallery)
3. Once the application gets created, I can't see anything in the "Provisioning" settings

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem I've described above. Unfortunately, I somehow the big blue "Get Started" button in the middle of the screen. When you click this button, the configuration I've been looking for appears and it is all good.
[image]